# connect to a github repository using libgit2sharp without cloning

Tags: c#, libgit2sharp

is it possible to connect to a github repository using libgit2sharp without cloning locally the repository? I need to read informations about the commits

Answer (score 1):

Through LibGit2Sharp, without cloning it first, one can read information about the references (mostly branches and tags) of the remote repository. This will retrieve the name of those references and the sha of the commit each one points to.

This can be done through the `IEnumerable<Reference> ListRemoteReferences(string url)` static method. This is the equivalent of the **[git ls-remote](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html)** CLI command.

Would you need more information on the commits, two options exists:

- Locally clone the remote repository
- Leverage the **[Commit GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/commits/#get-a-commit)**

Comment: @LucaMorelli Did this answer provide you with any help?